# what does 無駄にコマから出てくるな mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I've been reading a manga and there was a sentence:

> 無駄にコマから出てくるな

Can someone tell me what does it mean?

Comment: I know exactly what it means, but as a rule here, you would need to provide your own attempt first.

Comment: コマ amounts to the illustration together with the frame surrounding it. Does this help?

Comment: I'm sorry @l'électeur, I'm new here. I still have a problem with understanding this sentence. I thought that maybe it means something like: it's waste of illustration so don't show yourself.

Comment: @l'électeur could you point me in the direction of where this rule is written?

Comment: @sova [here](https://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799)

Comment: @YangMuye Thanks, that comment lead me to re-interpret the line.

Comment: It sounds like a つっこみ. 無駄に means “meaninglessly”, but it is often used to add some humorous effect. The whole sentence means “don't come out of the frame, which is pointless.” It may look like [this](http://d2dcan0armyq93.cloudfront.net/photo/odai/400/37f1f6a1777d6a9773454a2657cb947d_400.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question still is open, I'll try to answer it.

Your attempt,

> it's waste of illustration so don't show yourself.

is very much off.

1. This is the 'pensive' or 'monologue' な, not the imperative な

   - On second thought, this is debatable. I originally took the sentence to be something the mangaka wrote, criticising his/her own style.
2. コマ means 'frame (of a comic)'
3. This is the particle から ('from'), not 〜だから ('because')
4. Do check the dictionary for 出る (and/or 出てくる). Here it means 'to come out'
5. 'Waste of xxx' is typically 「xxxの無駄」

   無駄に, when used this way, means 'pointlessly' or 'for no purpose'

A correct answer would be (if we consider it to be the pensive な),

> [something] is coming out of the comic frame for no good reason

'Something' here, I presume, is referring to whatever is in the frame that is sticking out.

If we take it as a command, it's

> Don't stick out of the comic for no reason!

Answer (score 1):

"Don't stick out of the frame pointlessly" or "Don't stick out of the frame so much."